# Is nativescript running on Android 4 mobiles?

Tags: nativescript

Does nativescript work on Android 4?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. As of today the earliest API level it supports is 17 / v4.2.

I think there are less than 1% of devices still running Android 4. Most apps / SDKs today do not support versions below 6 or 5.

Comment: Thanks, then I am lucky. It will work on my device.osVersion 4.2.2